# Get tokens between two commands

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

I'm trying to create a `screenplay`-like class that uses a very simple syntax to create the dialogue, *and* dumps it as a plain text file for use in subtitles. To divide the subtitle sections I use `&`, `^` sets a new speaker, like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\^=13
\def^#1: {\par \textbf{#1:}}
\catcode`\&=13
\def&{\par \hspace{10pt}}
\begin{document}
 ^Alice: &Hello Bob. &What's up?
 ^Bob: &Nothing, really. &Goodbye.
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to get at the text between `&...&` (i.e. from `&` to just before the next `&`, so `&a&b&c` should expand to `\foo{a}\foo{b}\foo{c}`) to save it with a running index to my text file. So I tried `\bgroup`/`egroup` as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\def\testcommand{\textcolor{blue}}
\catcode`\^=13
\def^#1: {\egroup \par \textbf{#1:} \bgroup}
\catcode`\&=13
\def&{\egroup \par \hspace{10pt} \testcommand\bgroup}
\begin{document}
 \bgroup
 ^Alice: &Hello Bob. &What's up?
 ^Bob: &Nothing, really. &Goodbye.
 \egroup
\end{document}
```

And it seems to work, since `\textcolor` doesn't just colorize the next letter but the whole line, but when I use `\def\testcommand#1{(#1)}` it is called with an empty argument (produces *() Hello Bob. () What…*).

I guess this has something to do with the fact that when I use `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` with *my* `\testcommand` nothing changes but `\textcolor` breaks with `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup` on the first `&`.

In `color.sty` they use `\def\textcolor#1#` which I have never seen before (and when I use it with my `testcommand` it breaks with `\begin{document} ended by \end{)}`. What magic is that? Very difficult to google…

My other attempt `\def&#1&{ \testcommand{#1} }` doesn't work either because it eats the next `&`… (is there some kind of lookahead? So I could use `\def&` and eat tokens until the next one would be `&` or `^`?)

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Would the »sffms« class be an option for you?

Comment: No, because I want to be able to render multiple versions of the script from the same source (only dialogue/one character highlighted/plain text dumped for subtitles etc). So I have to redefine all commands I use anyway for each output type, and I want a very simple syntax for easy conversion. The other packages are 'too TeXy', but maybe I'll use them as one backend for mine…

Comment: Your code "works for me" doesn't compile (but it does if lines 3 and 4 are interchanged). Moreover, your should post solutions in an answer, not in the question. Yes! It is quite OK if you answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post somehow gives a `too many questions` overflow error. Let me try and answer a bit: You just can't pass an argument to a macro by using `\testcommand\bgroup <argument>\egroup`. This will only pass `\bgroup` to your `\testcommand`.

And yes, your definition `\def&#1&{ \testcommand{#1} }` does exactly this: It looks for the text between the `&` signs, and `&<some text>&` will be replaced with  `\testcommand{#1}` . Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\testcommand#1{(#1)}
\catcode`\^=13
\def^#1: {\par \textbf{#1:}}
\catcode`\&=13
\def&#1&{\ifx\relax#1\relax\else
         \par \hspace{10pt} \testcommand{#1} \expandafter&\fi}
\begin{document}
 ^Alice: &Hello Bob. &What's up?
 ^Bob: &Nothing, really. &Goodbye. &&
\end{document}
```

Note that I used `&&` to indicate the end of the script.

As for your question about `\def\textcolor#1#`, this makes `\textcolor` a macro that takes one argument *delimited by* `{`. Since the definition is

```
\def\textcolor#1#{\@textcolor{#1}}
```

this means that you can use `\textcolor<color-model>{...`, and this will expand to `\@textcolor{<color-model>}{...`. Note that `<color-model>` acts as an optional argument that mustn't contain `{`.

Comment: (Since I don't really know what I'm talking about I wanted to be very detailed, hence the length) But that doesn't work with an odd number of `&`'s. And it applies the `\testcommand` only to every other line.

Comment: @pascal: Yes, that's what is supposed to happen in my code. I wasn't sure what you wanted to achieve. Now I understand. The problem: You probably do _not_ want to get the text between subsequent `&` signs. In my modified answer, see what happens if you do that.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I wanted. Thanks! Adjusted my question.

Comment: @pascal: If you add `&&` after `What's up?`, do you then get what you want?

Comment: Yes, I adjusted my definition of `^` to add it before the next `^`.

Comment: @pascal: I don't quite see how you're doing that, but I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: updated the question with my solution. `&` now nested in `^` which appends the `&&` (makes more sense in my greater context)

Comment: Ah but a new problem came up: I only write the text captured between `&` to my output file. The text that isn't captured for example `^foo: bar\\ ` gets set into the normal output, which I don't want. My attempt at wrapping it all in an `\edef` failed (I thought it would be expanded, thus written to the file, and the resulting stray characters stored in my dummy macro I never call) Is there some kind of `\ignore{...}` command? All the solutions I came up with were very nasty, like shoving it to the end and cutting of the junk pages it generates …Or should I put that in a separate question?

Comment: @pascal: I'm really not sure what you're trying to do. In `^Alice: &Hello Bob. &What's up?\\ `, the `Alice: ` also isn't captured: Is that intended or not? And in `^foo: bar\\ `, _what_ do you want to capture? Only the `bar`? Then put `&` in front of it!

Comment: Posted it http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/ here as a seperate question, and I even found a strange answer

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\^=13
\catcode`\&=13
\def^#1: #2\\{\par \textbf{#1:} #2 &&}
\def\testcommand#1{(#1)}
\def&#1&{%
  \ifx\relax#1\else%
    \par\hspace{10pt}%
    \testcommand{#1}%
    \expandafter&%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
 ^Alice: &Hello Bob. &What's up?\\
 ^Bob: &Nothing, really. &Goodbye.\\
\end{document}
```