# Retain side-effects but discard command output

Tags: tex-core

The following code works, although I have a feeling my `\settowidth` method of discarding the output is not how it should be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\trashlength}
\long\def\ignoreoutput#1{%
 \settowidth{\trashlength}{#1}%
}
\long\def\command#1{
 This \gdef\stuff{Stored: #1} shouldn't be here.
}
%% Should not raise Missing \begin{document} error here:
%\ignoreoutput{\command}
\begin{document}
 % Should produce "nothing":
 no\ignoreoutput{\command{Side %\par %%%%% this breaks everything.  
 effect!}}thing.

 % Should output the text previously stored:
 \ifx\stuff\undefined No side effect.
 \else \stuff \fi
\end{document}
```

When uncommenting the `\par` though, it breaks: with *Paragraph ended before \@settodim was complete.*

So how do I ignore commands that allow long input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\newsavebox{\trashbox}
\long\def\ignoreoutput#1{\setbox\trashbox\vbox{\everypar{}\globaldefs1 #1}}
```

seems to work.

(**Edit:** make assignments global as per TH's answer, and locally disable LaTeX's `\everypar`-based mechanism for complaining about a missing \begin{document}.)

Comment: Ah, very short. Must have missed it when looking up `\savebox` etc... But it doesn't work before `\begin{document}` though (but I could defer it using `AtBeginDocument`)

Comment: @pascal: That can be fixed. See my edits above. I *think* it would be safe to forgo the usage of `\newsavebox` and just use `\setbox0` as in TH's answer, even without the extra group that he uses – since box registers with numbers below 10 are reserved for temporary use.

Comment: Perfect. I used `\long\def\ignoreoutput#1{\setbox0\vbox{\everypar{}#1}}` and it works. (since I use local macros in the ignored command, I prefer manual `\gdef`)

Comment: Good call on the `\everypar{}`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use something similar to Harald's example (which appeared just before I posted this).

```
\long\def\executeglobally#1{
        \begingroup
        \setbox0\vbox{
                \globaldefs1
                #1%
        }%
        \endgroup
}

\def\foo{foo}
\executeglobally{asdf\def\foo{bar}asdf}
\foo
\bye
```

The `\globaldefs1` makes assignments global.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about `\globaldefs` or temporary boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this, but it seems even fishier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\trashlength}
\newsavebox{\trashbox}
\long\def\ignoreoutput#1{%
    \sbox{\trashbox}{#1}%
    \settowidth{\trashlength}{\usebox{\trashbox}}%
}
% etc like above
```

But it can break with *Dimension too large*.