# Hide part of a document but process the side effects

Tags: boxes, pgfplotstable

This is a follow-up on the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/retain-side-effects-but-discard-command-output). I found two cases where the proposed solutions fail, and I am looking for ways to address it. Consider the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\long\def\ignoreThis#1{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox0\vbox{{\everypar{}
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        #1\end{minipage}}}%
\endgroup}%

\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}
Note that \ignoreThis{this text is not shown but \addtocounter{mycounter}{5}}
side effects are processed: \themycounter
\end{document}
```

This works well except in two cases that I have identified (I am sure there are more as these seem related to output to aux files).

```
\ignoreThis{\begin{equation}
    \label{eq} A=B \end{equation}
  Reference inside \ref{eq}.}
```

This causes the warning `Reference 'eq' on page 1 undefined`. I could redefine `\ref` locally in `\ignoreThis`, but I doubt this is a good a solution. Another more critical issue is caused by `pgfplots`:

```
\ignoreThis{\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}
      \addplot[only marks,mark=*]%
      table[x=x, y=y] {x  y
        2 4
        4 4
        3 3};
    \end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I get the error `Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file`. I am able to workaround this issue by defining the table outside `\ignoreThis` and using it in a plot.

Is there a better way to fix these issues?

Comment: \include is designed for this if you omit a section with includeonly all labels and counters are preserved

Comment: Oh I didn't know `\include` preserves counters. Yes, that does seem to work.  Although, `\include` adds a `\clearpage` before and after, but maybe there is a way to disable that. More importantly, would this mean that I have to create (and keep track of) a separate file every time I want to hide part of my document? In my use case, I actually control the inclusion of the content inside my command with a toggle. And I actually use this command tens of times (to hide solutions to questions in an exam paper).

Comment: yes include needs separate files and a clearpage so it is not for all use cases

Comment: There is a way of doing it in LuaTeX. Basically, you can inspect the corresponding glyph nodes and vlist nodes generated by the content in `\ignoreThis` and replace them with empty nodes of the same dimensions. Unfortunately I do not have a lot of time recently and I am not good enough in LuaTeX to give you an answer quickly. Maybe you can rephrase your question in LuaTeX-related form and consult with some of the LuaTeX experts here.